Is it possible to make a colour-blind friendly RGB option in "color" for ax.scatter?
I have scatter plot in which I have colour coded the scatter points according to the relative contribution of 3 factors. I use the red, green and blue channels to represent this. This works really nicely in terms of highlighting problematic configurations.
The issue I have is that in order to make this more widely readable I need to make it colour-blind friendly. Intuitively I feel like this should be possible by replacing the base red, green and blue with other colours. However, I can't see how to achieve this.
For context, the solution that worked the best for my application was to create a smaller 3D subplot which shows the physical meaning behind the different colours. The code below shows the creation of that key, which is itself a scatter plot.
import numpy as np # version 1.19.2
import matplotlib as mp # version 3.3.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d
import scipy.misc as misc
import glob
import pdb
 
####### 3D cube legend ####
class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)


fig1 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig1.add_axes([0.,0.,1,1],projection='3d')
r = np.arange(0,101,1)[::2]

ax2.invert_xaxis()
intr = 4
X, Y = np.meshgrid(r, r)
XX,YY = np.meshgrid(r[::-1],r[::-1])
for i in r:
    for j in r:
        rot = 40
        # see the commented out lines here
        ax2.scatter(i,0,j,s=50,color=(i/100.,0,j/100.),marker=(4,0,rot))#, cmap="viridis")
        ax2.scatter(i,j,0,s=50,color=(i/100.,j/100.,0),marker=(4,0,rot))#, cmap="viridis")
        ax2.scatter(0,i,j,s=50,color=(0,i/100.,j/100.),marker=(4,0,rot))#, cmap="viridis")

ax2.view_init(-30,-45)
a = Arrow3D([0,110],[0,0],[0,0],mutation_scale=20,lw=3,arrowstyle='-|>',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,color='grey')
ax2.add_artist(a)
a = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,110],[0,0],mutation_scale=20,lw=3,arrowstyle='-|>',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,color='grey')
ax2.add_artist(a)
a = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,0],[0,110],mutation_scale=20,lw=3,arrowstyle='-|>',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,color='grey')
ax2.add_artist(a)
ax2.patch.set_visible(False)

for i in np.arange(10,110,10):
    ax2.plot([0,101.5],[i,i],[0,0],lw=1,color='grey',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,linestyle='--') # x
    ax2.plot([0,101.5],[0,0],[i,i],lw=1,color='grey',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,linestyle='--') # x
    ax2.plot([i,i],[0,101.5],[0,0],lw=1,color='grey',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,linestyle='--') # y
    ax2.plot([0,0],[0,101.5],[i,i],lw=1,color='grey',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,linestyle='--') # y
    ax2.plot([0,0],[i,i],[0,101.5],lw=1,color='grey',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,linestyle='--') # z
    ax2.plot([i,i],[0,0],[0,101.5],lw=1,color='grey',zorder=6*len(r)**2+1,linestyle='--') # z

for i in np.arange(20,120,20):
    ax2.text(i+5,110,0,str(float(i)/400.),zorder=6*len(r)**2+2,fontsize=12)
    ax2.text(115,i,0,str(float(i)/100.),zorder=6*len(r)**2+2,fontsize=12)
    ax2.text(0,105,i,str(float(i)/100.),zorder=6*len(r)**2+2,fontsize=12)

ax2.text2D(0.07,0.04,r"Variable a",zorder=6*len(r)**2+3,transform=ax2.transAxes,rotation=-23,fontsize=35)
ax2.text2D(0.56,0.04,r"Variable b",zorder=6*len(r)**2+3,transform=ax2.transAxes,rotation=23,fontsize=35)
ax2.text2D(0.96,0.33,r"Variable c",zorder=6*len(r)**2+3,transform=ax2.transAxes,rotation=-88,fontsize=35)

plt.axis("off")
fig1.set_size_inches(11, 9)
plt.draw()
plt.show()

I have tried to change the colour map to something else (e.g. see the hashed out cmap="viridis") but this is ignored. I feel like something along the lines of this is the way to go, i.e. changing the base colours from red-green-blue, but only if it is not ignored once created.
Effectively, what I want to be able to do is have the ax2.scatter(...,color=(R,G,B)) point to a colour map which is colour-blind friendly.

There is more than one kind of  colour blindness. The most common being red-green. Your best bet might be to use luminosity as one of the colours. You probably want to use the Ishihara color blindness test plates to guide you as to which false colour mapping makes sense to a given colour blind viewer

Actually yes there color codes for this
Here some color codes
    (0, 114, 178),   # Blue
    (230, 159, 0),   # Orange
    (86, 180, 233),  # Sky Blue
    (0, 158, 115),   # Bluish Green
    (240, 228, 66),  # Yellow
    (204, 121, 167), # Reddish Purple
    (213, 94, 0),    # Vermillion
    (0, 0, 0),       # Black
]

# Normalize to RGB [0, 1] for matplotlib
colorblind_palette = [(r / 255, g / 255, b / 255) for r, g, b in colorblind_palette]```

